Add a compiler C preprocessor macro (-D option) in a C++ header file
I want to add a C preprocessor macro to the compilation of any translation unit which includes a header file, using the clang compiler.
In essence I would like to do something similar to suppressing warnings only for specific header includes:
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wsome-warning-like-unused-variable"
#include <some_header>
#pragma clang diagnostic pop

But instead of this, I would like to have a macro definition added
#define SOME_MACRO_DEFINITION
#include <some_header>
#undef SOME_MACRO_DEFINTION

For context, the compilation error occurs when including boost headers which use std::unary_function. The Xcode 14.3 workaround suggested is to define this macro: _LIBCPP_ENABLE_CXX17_REMOVED_UNARY_BINARY_FUNCTION https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-14_3-release-notes
I can enable this macro on a global scope using my build system (by passing -D_LIBCPP_ENABLE_CXX17_REMOVED_UNARY_BINARY_FUNCTION as a flag to the compiler), but really I'd like to only enable it for compiling the source files which include the specific offending boost headers. Unfortunately, I can't change the build system drastically. Ideally, I only modify the source code.

What's the problem with the approach you've showed -- defining a macro before including and undefining after?

It doesn't work :( Presumably because it just defines a macro but does not add it as a compiler option (-D). I could well be wrong in my reasoning, however,

_LIBCPP_ENABLE_CXX17_REMOVED_UNARY_BINARY_FUNCTION must be defined when including C++ standard headers (in particular functional), not Boost headers. If you have something like #include <functional> #define ThatMacro #include <boost/something> #undef ThatMacro then the macro is defined too late. Also, <functional> could be included indirectly by other headers (C++ standard headers or your own), making it hard to guarantee that #define ThatMacro is early enough unless you put it at the top of the source file, before any includes. Defining it via -D option basically does just that.

@IgorTandetnik this looks like an answer. Could you post it as one?
